# Two ArrayList in run() method Collision Detection

Tags: java, arraylist, collision-detection, collision, rectangles

i have problem with checking collision with 2 arraylist that updating in run() method. here is my code in run() method:

```
 ArrayList enemy = addenemy.getEnemy();
        for (int i = 0; i < enemy.size(); i++) {
            Enemy p = (Enemy) enemy.get(i);
            if (p.isVisible() == true) {
                p.update();                    
            } else {
                enemy.remove(i);

            }}

ArrayList bullets = CharS.getBullets();
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
            Bullets p = (Bullets) bullets.get(i);
            if (p.isVisible() == true) {
                p.update();
            } else {
                bullets.remove(i);

            }}
```

and here is my collision code in bullet class.

```
private void checkCollision() {
    ArrayList enemy = Game.getEnemy();
        for (int i = 0; i < enemy.size(); i++) {
            Enemy e = (Enemy) enemy.get(i);

        if(r.intersects(e.r)){
        visible = false;

        System.out.println("SHOTED");

        }}}
```

i got error when when enemy object removed(out of screen). how can i resolve this? thanks

Comment: "i got error" - Okay, what's the error?

Comment: i got this messages : Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The exception stack trace should show what line of code caused the NPE. Please identify what line of code in your posted code caused the exception. Also, what is `r` in the `checkCollision` method?

Comment: this line `if(r.intersects(e.r)){` caused the exception.
r is rectangle of bullets. its running normaly before enemy pass away from screen `enemy.remove(i);`. @Ted-Hopp

Comment: If that line is throwing a NPE, then either `r` or `e` is `null` when that line executes. (Or perhaps `e.r`, if the NPE is being thrown from within the call to `intersects`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you definining `r` as anything? I don't see anywhere where `r` is defined. This would cause your NullPointerException error.

Check the stack trace for the line number that the error is occurring on.

Comment: thank you guys, its caused `r=null;` in my code. now my app running normally after delete it. thanks.